# what is view=cm&fs=1 stands from the Eamil redirecting link

Tags: php, html, email

This is the link for open a mail with **To** address and **bcc** may i know what are the other variables we are sending like **`view=cm&fs=1`**

```
<div class="pull-right manu-say">
<span class="text-primary">Say hi at: </span>
<a  href="mailto://hola@gmail.com?view=cm&fs=1&to=hola@gmail.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=sunild@gmail.net" target="_blank" >hola@gmail.com</a>
</div>
```

And one more thing i gave target="_blank" which is not working. i want to open in a new tab.
any one help me out

Comment: why negative man..?

Comment: I down voted because: We have no way to what the two things means in your local system, and if the two variables are global / not only relevant to your local system then you'll most likely be able to find a explanation of what they do online / via what ever service is creating those links.

Comment: @Epodax can you see the answer you misunderstood the question man. without having proper knowledge why u vote down. let someone to learn bro..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

view=cm means open the compose message view

fs=1 means open it in fullscreen mode